# http request statistics in wireshark

Tags: http, httprequest, wireshark

Searched the web for 2 hours because of this (so a good link to relevant topics will be more then welcome).

In the statistics of HTTP requests in wireshark (Statistics-> HTTP-> Requests), what does the column **Rate (ms)** refer to (highlighted in the image)??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the wireshark website forum, I found the following answer:

http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/24857/what-exactly-does-the-ratems-mean-in-the-protocol-specific-stats-window

rate(ms) refers to "the average packet rate"

Comment: How come it took you 5 minutes to find it, and I spent almost 2 hours?? thanks!!

Comment: :) Maybe I used better keywords?
I googled: 'wireshark rate' and voila! :)